# Mostrar 1 sola columna con la clausula TOP en sql cuando tengo que realizar un count() para sacar un total

Tags: sql

Buen dia estimados, tengo la tabla usuarios y despues tengo la tabla compras, lo que estoy buscando es hacer un count para sacar el listado de compras y luego con este count, mostrar con un TOP solo el nombre del usuario y no mostrar la cantidad de compras. La consulta que tengo para sacar el total de compras es la siguiente.

```
select [VARIOS].DBO.USUARIOS.NOMBREYAPE as Nombre_Usuario, count(ID_USUARIO) as Compras from COMPRAS INNER JOIN [VARIOS].DBO.USUARIOS on ID_USUARIO = [VARIOS].DBO.ID_USUARIO where FECHA between '20200401' and '20200430' group by [VARIOS].DBO.USUARIOS.NOMBREYAPE order by COMPRAS desc
```

Y la consulta que tengo para hacer el top es la siguiente

```
Select top 1 [VARIOS].DBO.USUARIOS.NOMBREYAPE as Nombre_Usuario, count(ID_USUARIO) as Compras from Compras INNER JOIN [VARIOS].DBO.USUARIOS on ID_USUARIO = [VARIOS].DBO.ID_USUARIO where MOD_FEC between '20200401' and '20200430' group by [VARIOS].DBO.USUARIOS.NOMBREYAPE  order by Compras desc
```

Con esta consulta me trae nombre y apellido y la cantidad de Compras. Yo lo que deseo es solo traer el nombre y apellido, pero sin hacer el count nose como. He buscado en varias paginas, pero no encuentro nada que me aclare la duda. Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: No entiendo tu consulta.. si solo queres mostrar un nombre lo mostras.. tu count no hace nada en esa consulta, solo cuenta un campo.. porque directamente no lo sacas y el group by tambien? o falta algo en lo que necesitas?

Comment: Quiero mostrar el nombre del que mas compras ha realizado. Cada vez que se realiza una compra, en la tabla compras se carga con el id, entonces contando los ids puedo saber quien fue el que mas compras realizo, esto lo hago mediante el count. Por lo tanto el count si tiene una funcion especifica que es contar la cantidad de compras que realizo cada usuario y mostrarlo.

Comment: Fijate que eso, no lo pusiste en la pregunta... esto es simplemente usar tu consulta como ingreso de una nueva que muestre un solo registro y solo el nombre del campo que queres...

Comment: Tenes razon, esta mal formulada la pregunta. ya que como vos decis, si quiero mostrar una sola columna, pongo esa columna y listo, se puede editar el titulo? o tengo que formular una nueva pregunta?

Comment: usa el boton [edit]. podes modificar todo. igual, entendiste que tenes que hacer para solucionar tu problema?

Comment: si, ahi lo edite, pero igual no entiendo como tengo que hacer para solo mostrar el nombre y apellido ya que en el select tengo que poner el count para sacar el total , no le veo la manera de usar el count pero no mostrarlo.

Comment: sabes sobre subconsultas? porque tu solucion es por ahi

Comment: Gracias Gonzalo, ahi lo pude hacer con una subconsulta como me indicaste. Hice un select "usuario" from (Aca puse la consulta con el top, usuario y el count) y ya me quedo.. Te agradezco mucho. Saludos

Comment: GEnial... ahora agrega una respuesta completa ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude solucionar haciendo una subconsulta. Dejo el código por si a alguien le sirve.

```
Select t.Nombre_Usuario

(Select top 1 [VARIOS].DBO.USUARIOS.NOMBREYAPE as Nombre_Usuario, count(ID_USUARIO) as Compras from Compras INNER JOIN [VARIOS].DBO.USUARIOS on ID_USUARIO = [VARIOS].DBO.ID_USUARIO where FECHA between '20200401' and '20200430' group by [VARIOS].DBO.USUARIOS.NOMBREYAPE  order by Compras desc) t
```

saludos